# cordova 3.4.0 installation error

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create project in cordova i am getting follwing error

```
        C:\xampp\htdocs\tagcordova\sample>cordova -d platform add android'
   Platform "android'" not recognized as a core cordova platform. See "platform lis
    t".

   C:\xampp\htdocs\tagcordova\sample>cordova -d platform add android
  cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
  Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
  Creating android project...
  Running command: cmd args=["/c","C:\\Users\\Bhanuprakash\\.cordova\\lib\\android
  \\cordova\\3.4.0\\bin\\create","--cli","C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tagcordova\\sample\\p
  latforms\\android","com.tag.sample","Sample"]
  Command finished with error code ENOENT: cmd /c,C:\Users\Bhanuprakash\.cordova\l
 ib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create,--cli,C:\xampp\htdocs\tagcordova\sample\plat
 forms\android,com.tag.sample,Sample
 Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Bhanuprakash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:795:12)
```

i follwed following article  http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html
please tell me how to solve the problem.

Comment: try to run `C:\Users\Bhanuprakash\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\check_reqs.bat` in a cmd shell to see what it outputs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure of yours paths try to type `android` in cmd, if it says: `'xcopy' was not recognized`.

then add to your path:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
```

Comment: what variable name i have to give please give extra information how to add path in environment variable %SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;

Comment: i am getting follwing error Creating android project...
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\Bhanuprakash\.cordova\lib\and
roid\cordova\3.4.0\VERSION'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)

Comment: superb dude... thank you .. its working now properly

Answer (score 1):

```
cordova -d platform add android'
```

try

```
cordova -d platform add android
```

Comment: Do you have exactly the same error ? because you had a " ' " at the end of "android"

Comment: i am getting same error clem.. i am strugling to start cordova .

Comment: Have you installed the android SDK ? Follow this [link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)

Comment: i set enviornment path for android sdk platformtools and tools also

Answer (score 1):

Hi problem is with android sdk.

Ensure you are using adt-bundle-windows and set following environment path.

Start -> Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Environment variables -> System variables

1. ANDROID_HOME: C:\Nithi\software\Android_sdk\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-       bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\
2. path: "Existing path";%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

"Existing path": already system paths will be there.

1. delete .cordova and .android in C:\Users\youruser>
2. close command prompt and open.
3. phonegap run android or cordova platform add android

hope with will work!!!!

Comment: i am getting follwing error Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Bhanuprakash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:795:12)

Comment: Hi problem is with environment variables. Mainly on ant path.      Check your path configurations. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119282/phonegap-3-3-project-creation-through-node/21783756#21783756                           And ensure, there should not be space while creating new project.

Comment: i tried my dear. but still i am getting this error Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Bhanuprakash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:795:12)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. can you ensure all this configuration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523155/cant-run-phonegaps-create-command/21784683#21784683. check my installation procedure setp by step.

Comment: Hi @NithyanandanSathiyanathan : I have followed the stems that you have mentioned.. I get this error
cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
Creating android project...
Running command: "C:\Users\Aditya Sethi\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\c
reate.bat" --cli "c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\Documents\Project\conference\platforms\a
ndroid" com.phonegap.helloworld HelloWorld
'C:\Users\Aditya' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Command finished with error code 1: C:\Users\Aditya Sethi\.cordova\lib\android\c
ordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat --cli,c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\Documents\Project\confer
ence\platforms\android,com.phonegap.helloworld,HelloWorld
Error: C:\Users\Aditya Sethi\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat:
Command failed with exit code 1
  at ChildProcess.whenDone (c:\Users\Aditya Sethi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
  at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit