# Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK

Tags: java, cordova

i am getting this error during making phonegap build

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The followin
g error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The followin
g error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Unable to fi
nd a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25"

Total time: 45 seconds



D:\xampp\htdocs\mymind\mymind\mymind\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.
js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\xampp\htdocs\mymi
nd\mymind\mymind\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.
dir=ant-gen
```

i think problem with the PATH which i have added to the system variables of the windows envirement variables.

- JAVA_HOME -> C:\Program
  Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25;C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre

**another error**

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The followin
g error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null returne
d: 1

Total time: 14 seconds


D:\xampp\htdocs\mymind\mymind\mymind\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.
js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,D:\xampp\htdocs\mymi
nd\mymind\mymind\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.
dir=ant-gen

Error: D:\xampp\htdocs\mymind\mymind\mymind\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat:
 Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\umar.farooq\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspaw
n.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25"

`jre` stands for Java Runtime Environment, and you need `jdk` which is Java Development Kit.

So, `JAVA_HOME` should point to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`, and in your `PATH` system variable you should have `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin`.

Comment: rebuilding app i will let you know if this not works.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of `PATH` variable, so this probably won't fix it. Will delete it as wrong and misleading.

Comment: I've rewrote my answer, can you check it and see if it helps?

Comment: its still giving me this error although i have replace the path  Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25"                            JAVA_HOME                                                              C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin

Comment: Your `JAVA_HOME` should be without `bin` at the end. Also, it seems that old value with `jre` is cached in your IDE, so try to restart it (if it still reports old value, try restarting your computer). Again, remove `bin` from `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: yes this is fixed but now i have another error occur can u help me to fix this too?

Comment: Don't know, but take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991124/cordova-3-4-0-installation-error) for possible solutions.

Comment: I updated my JAVA_HOME but when I run cocos deploy it still says it is pointing to the jre...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the Java SE SDK and not the Java EE SDK, because android wouldn't recognize the second.